# Show raw values and weighted mean for each factor level in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to show a variable (Allele specific expression) for different factor levels (samples) and the weighted mean (weight=coverage).

I have made some sample data:

```
set.seed(2)
x <- sample(c("A","B","C"), 100, replace=T)
y <- rnorm(100)
w <- ceiling(rnorm(100,200,200))
df <- data.frame(x, y, w)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(x), y=y, weight=w)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=w)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="red", geom="point", size=5)
```

(and I tried to post the plot as well - but I do not have enough points yet).

This works fine - but it shows the unweighted mean...

```
library(plyr)
means <- ddply(df, "x", function(x) data.frame(wm=weighted.mean(x$y, x$w),
                                               m=mean(x$y)))
means

 x          wm           m
1 A  0.00878432  0.11027454
2 B -0.07283770 -0.13605530
3 C -0.14233389  0.08116117
```

So - I am just trying to show the "wm" values as red dots instead - using ggplot2. I think it must be using the "weight=.." correctly - but I am giving up now...

I really hope somebody can help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd create the `summary` data.frame with `mean` and `weighted mean` first as follows:

```
require(plyr)
dd <- ddply(df, .(x), summarise, m=mean(y), wm=weighted.mean(y, w))
```

Then, I'd plot by loading this data for showing the mean and the weighted mean.

```
require(reshape2) # for melt
require(ggplot2)
ggplot() + geom_point(data = df, aes(x=factor(x), y=y, size=w)) + 
          geom_point(data = melt(dd, id.var="x"), 
          aes(x=x, y=value, colour=variable), size=5) 

# if you want to remove the legend "variable"
scale_colour_discrete(breaks=NULL)
```

[image]

You might want to consider using `scale_size_area()` to provide a better/unbiased size to value allocation.

Comment: Thank you - you just saved my weekend!

Comment: Hi again. Not really new to SO - but mostly reading answers (since most questions in my area has been asked at least once before ;) ). I tried to accept immediately, but was forced to wait a while by the system. Anyway: thanks a lot for fast help.